# Is there any possibilities for 0 quantity place order?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart, quantity

Magento automatically assumes the cart quantity to 1 while the quantity in product is 0 (It's correct way and still a good one), I would like to know the possibilities to send the 0 qty to cart and checkout. let me know which function handle this.

Comment: I don't think this is logical. What is 0 product means? can you have a 0 son? so I will flag this question. @marius check once

Comment: @PrakashThapa It's not logical, yet I am surprised which observer in magento takes into account of adding 1 to 0 qty from product.